# Force compile nodejs with nodebuild

Tags: asdf

I am trying to compile nodejs (20.0.0) using nodebuild in asdf.

Link: https://github.com/asdf-vm/asdf-nodejs

Command line usage: asdf nodejs nodebuild --definitions

unsure of the CLI usage.